# Extent report is Save only the last one results of the last one job in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, report, jobs

I 'am Using Extent Report with Testng And when I am running the jobs I have Only the last one report for last executed job
I want to save the extent report for all jobs??
Any Idea ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Solved by OP:

There is an option in Jenkins "Keep past HTML reports" just activate it and it will save old reports too.

Old answer:
You are probably saving the file as `results` or something that is not unique so it will rewrite the file every time...

What you should do is save the result file with a time stamp so it won't be rewritten.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its solved thanks you , but with other way there is option in jenkins   Keep past HTML reports   i activate and its work